# Oracle CLOB slow running report

Tags: coldfusion, oracle10g, reporting

We have a report that pulls data from an Oracle 10g database.
We are using Coldfusion 9 to display the report.
The report contains 3 CLOB columns that is killing the report processing time.
Tested this by removing the three CLOB columns and report displays in 2 - 3 seconds.

Is there anything that can be done to increase the processing time of the report?
I understand why its running slow due to how large the CLOB fields are.
Just looking to improve the processing time.

Just to give an idea of rows typical report returns 200-300 row so very small amount of rows.

many thanks

Matthew

UPDATE - We have tried using dbms_lob.substr() and return max 4000 character but this does not improve the processing time.

here's the query:

```
        SELECT
            R.NC_REQUEST_ID     REQUEST_ID,
            R.TC_REQUEST_NAME   REQUEST_NAME,
            R.TC_REQUEST_NAME_2 REQUEST_NAME_2,
            R.TC_INITIATOR      INITIATOR,
            R.NC_EXPENSE        EXPENSE,                            
            S.NC_FORM_STEP_ID   FORM_STEP_ID,
            S.NC_FORM_ID        FORM_ID,
            S.NC_STEP_ID        STEP_ID,
            S.TC_STEP_CODE      STEP_CODE,
            S.TC_STEP_NAME      STEP_NAME,
            TO_CHAR(R.DC_SUBMIT_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY') SUBMIT_DATE,
            TO_CHAR(R.DC_ORIGINAL_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY')   ORIGINAL_DATE,
            TO_CHAR(R.DC_REVISION_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY')   REVISION_DATE,          
            R.NC_BUS_GROUP_ID_FK    BUS_GROUP_ID,
            R.NC_BUS_UNIT_ID_FK     BUS_UNIT_ID,
            R.NC_BUS_SUB_ID_FK      BUS_SUB_ID,
            R.TC_ACT_NUMBER         ACT_NUMBER,
            R.TC_REQUEST_NAME       REQUEST_NAME,
            R.NC_YEAR               YEAR_NUM,
            R.NC_ACT_END_NUMBER     ACT_END_NUMBER,
            R.DC_START_DATE     START_DATE,
            R.DC_END_DATE       END_DATE,
            R.NC_ACT_TYPE_ID_FK ACT_TYPE_ID_FK,
            TO_CHAR(R.DC_APPROVAL_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY')   APPROVAL_DATE,
            CC_ATTACHED_EXHIBIT                     ATTACHED_EXHIBIT,
            CC_ROUTED                               ROUTED,
            R.IC_RESTRICTED                         RESTRICTED,
            ROI.NC_PI_OFF PI_OFF,
            ROI.NC_PI_CA COST_AVOIDANCE_PI,
            (SELECT COUNT(NC_REQUEST_ID_FK) FROM TBXS31_REMOVE_SECTION WHERE NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND NC_TEMPLATE_ID_FK IN(346,1455,1456,1458,1459,1460,1464.1641) GROUP BY NC_REQUEST_ID_FK) AS COUNT_OF_REMOVE_SECTIONS,    
    <cfoutput query="variables.qryEnergyListItems"> 
        (SELECT NVL(ED.NC_EXISTINGUSAGE - ED.NC_PROPOSEDUSAGE,0) FROM TBYB28_SI_ENERGY_DATA ED,TBXP73_LIST_ITEMS LI WHERE LI.NC_VALUE_ID = ED.NC_ENERGYFORM(+) AND LI.NC_VALUE_ID = #variables.qryEnergyListItems.NC_VALUE_ID# AND ED.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND LI.IC_ACTIVE = 'T' AND LI.NC_VALUE_ID <> 808) AS "#variables.qryEnergyListItems.TC_MED_DESC#",
    </cfoutput>
            (SELECT TC_MED_DESC FROM TBXP73_LIST_ITEMS WHERE NC_VALUE_ID = SD.NC_BUSINESSUNIT) AS TC_BUS_UNIT,
            (SELECT TC_MED_DESC FROM TBXP73_LIST_ITEMS WHERE NC_VALUE_ID = SD.NC_BUSINESSSUBUNIT) AS TC_BUS_SUB_UNIT,
            (SELECT TC_MED_DESC FROM TBXP73_LIST_ITEMS WHERE NC_VALUE_ID = SD.NC_SITE) AS TC_BUS_SITE,
            (SELECT NC_PROPOSEDGHG - NC_EXISTINGGHG FROM TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA WHERE NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID) AS ANNUAL_IMPACT_C02E,
            (SELECT DECODE(TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_BASE_CO2E , 0, NULL, ((TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_PROPOSEDGHG - TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_EXISTINGGHG)   / TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_BASE_CO2E)  * 100) FROM TBYB14_SI_BASELINE,TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA WHERE TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_SITE = TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_SITE_ID_FK(+) AND TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_BASELINEYEAR = TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_YEAR(+) ) AS PCT_IMPACT_CO2E,
            (SELECT NC_PROPOSEDWASTE - NC_EXISTINGWASTE FROM TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA WHERE NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID) AS ANNUAL_IMPACT_WASTE,
            (SELECT DECODE(TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_BASE_WASTE, 0, NULL, ((TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_PROPOSEDWASTE - TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_EXISTINGWASTE) / TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_BASE_WASTE) * 100) FROM TBYB14_SI_BASELINE,TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA WHERE TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_SITE = TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_SITE_ID_FK(+) AND TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_BASELINEYEAR = TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_YEAR(+)  ) AS PCT_IMPACT_WASTE,
            (SELECT NC_PROPOSEDWATER - NC_EXISTINGWATER FROM TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA WHERE NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID) AS ANNUAL_IMPACT_WATER,
            (SELECT DECODE(TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_BASE_WATER, 0, NULL, ((TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_PROPOSEDWATER - TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_EXISTINGWATER) / TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_BASE_WATER) * 100) FROM TBYB14_SI_BASELINE,TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA WHERE TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_SITE = TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_SITE_ID_FK(+) AND TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA.NC_BASELINEYEAR = TBYB14_SI_BASELINE.NC_YEAR(+) ) AS PCT_IMPACT_WATER,
            (SELECT TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.TC_TEXT FROM TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS WHERE TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_TEMPLATE_ID_FK = 570 AND NC_SUBSECTION_ID = 0) AS PROPOSAL_TEXT,
            (SELECT TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.TC_TEXT FROM TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS WHERE TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_TEMPLATE_ID_FK = 1456 AND NC_SUBSECTION_ID = 0) AS COMMENTS_EXPLANATIONS,                          
            (SELECT TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.TC_TEXT FROM TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS WHERE TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_TEMPLATE_ID_FK = 1458 AND NC_SUBSECTION_ID = 0) AS COMMENTS_ON_ADD_SI_IMPACTS, 
   <!--- Get Capital --->
            (
        SELECT
            SUM(NVL((NC_QUANTITY * COST) * (1 + NC_TAX_RATE),0))
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    E.*,
                    NVL(E.MC_COST,0) * FROM_CURR.NC_EXCHANGE_RATE / TO_CURR.NC_EXCHANGE_RATE    COST,
                    E.MC_MAINT_COST * FROM_CURR.NC_EXCHANGE_RATE / TO_CURR.NC_EXCHANGE_RATE     MAINT_COST
                FROM
                    TBXS23_EXPENDITURES E,
                    TBXS41_EXCHANGE_RATE_CIT    FROM_CURR,
                    TBXS41_EXCHANGE_RATE_CIT    TO_CURR,
                    TBXP78_REQUESTS     R,
                    V_TBXS13_STEPS      SS
                WHERE
                    R.NC_ACT_TYPE_ID_FK != 40
                AND
                    R.NC_FORM_STEP_ID_FK = SS.NC_FORM_STEP_ID                   
                AND
                    E.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID 
                AND
                    TO_CURR.NC_CURRENCY_ID = <cfqueryparam value="#session.objUser.getCurrencyPreference()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"> 
                AND
                    E.NC_CURRENCY_ID_FK = FROM_CURR.NC_CURRENCY_ID 
                AND
                    E.NC_EXPENDITURE_TYPE_ID_FK = 83
                AND
                    R.DC_APPROVAL_DATE
                BETWEEN 
                    TO_CURR.DC_VALID_FROM 
                AND 
                    TO_CURR.DC_VALID_TO 
                AND
                    R.DC_APPROVAL_DATE
                BETWEEN 
                    FROM_CURR.DC_VALID_FROM 
                AND 
                    FROM_CURR.DC_VALID_TO

            ) WHERE NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID

        )AS CAPITAL,
 <!--- Get Capital --->

 <!--- Project Expense One Time --->
        (
        SELECT
            SUM(NVL((NC_QUANTITY * COST) * (1 + NC_TAX_RATE),0))
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    E.*,
                    NVL(E.MC_COST,0) * FROM_CURR.NC_EXCHANGE_RATE / TO_CURR.NC_EXCHANGE_RATE    COST,
                    E.MC_MAINT_COST * FROM_CURR.NC_EXCHANGE_RATE / TO_CURR.NC_EXCHANGE_RATE     MAINT_COST
                FROM
                    TBXS23_EXPENDITURES E,
                    TBXS41_EXCHANGE_RATE_CIT    FROM_CURR,
                    TBXS41_EXCHANGE_RATE_CIT    TO_CURR,
                    TBXP78_REQUESTS     R,
                    V_TBXS13_STEPS      SS
                WHERE
                    R.NC_ACT_TYPE_ID_FK != 40
                AND
                    R.NC_FORM_STEP_ID_FK = SS.NC_FORM_STEP_ID                   
                AND
                    E.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID 
                AND
                    TO_CURR.NC_CURRENCY_ID = <cfqueryparam value="#session.objUser.getCurrencyPreference()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
                AND
                    E.NC_EXPENDITURE_TYPE_ID_FK = 84 
                AND
                    E.NC_CURRENCY_ID_FK = FROM_CURR.NC_CURRENCY_ID 
                AND
                    R.DC_APPROVAL_DATE
                BETWEEN 
                    TO_CURR.DC_VALID_FROM 
                AND 
                    TO_CURR.DC_VALID_TO 
                AND
                    R.DC_APPROVAL_DATE
                BETWEEN 
                    FROM_CURR.DC_VALID_FROM 
                AND 
                    FROM_CURR.DC_VALID_TO

            ) WHERE NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID

        )AS PROJECT_EXPENSE 
  <!--- Project Expense One Time --->                
        FROM
            TBXP78_REQUESTS             R,
            V_TBXS13_STEPS              S,
            TBXS39_ROI                  ROI,
            TBYB27_SUSTAINABILITY_DATA  SD
        WHERE
            R.NC_FORM_STEP_ID_FK = S.NC_FORM_STEP_ID
        AND
            R.NC_REQUEST_ID = ROI.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK(+)
        AND
            R.NC_REQUEST_ID = SD.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK(+)
        AND
            R.NC_ACT_TYPE_ID_FK != 40
```

These are the CLOB fields:

```
            (SELECT TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.TC_TEXT FROM TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS WHERE TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_TEMPLATE_ID_FK = 570 AND NC_SUBSECTION_ID = 0) AS PROPOSAL_TEXT,
            (SELECT TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.TC_TEXT FROM TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS WHERE TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_TEMPLATE_ID_FK = 1456 AND NC_SUBSECTION_ID = 0) AS COMMENTS_EXPLANATIONS,                          
            (SELECT TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.TC_TEXT FROM TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS WHERE TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = R.NC_REQUEST_ID AND TBXS32_TEXT_SECTIONS.NC_TEMPLATE_ID_FK = 1458 AND NC_SUBSECTION_ID = 0) AS COMMENTS_ON_ADD_SI_IMPACTS,
```

Comment: Is the processing time a result of the query or of the browser rendering all that data?

Comment: The processing time is the result of the query running.

Comment: Posting the query might help.

Comment: The first thing I would try would be to run the clob stuff separately and assemble the results from the two queries with Q of Q.  I've  had success with that approach in the past.

Comment: I have tried it separatly already and doesn't make any difference to the procressing time.